# unique dart package names

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Is there any way of ensuring that package names are unique in Dart?
Java recommends that you use the reverse of you companies url. eg. com.foursee.mypackage 
I have noticed that the dart packages are prefixed with "dart" e.g. "dart:math"

Should I do something similar for a package I am developing?

e.g. "foursee:quadtree"

There is no sign of other package developers doing something this.

Answer (score 2):

The `dart:` prefix is used for built-in libraries bundled with the *Dart SDK*.

> For built-in libraries, the URI has the special `dart:` scheme. For other libraries, you can use a file system path or the `package:` scheme. The `package:` scheme specifies libraries provided by a package manager such as the pub tool.

See [Using Libraries](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#libraries-import).

Packages published on [Pub](http://pub.dartlang.org) are identified only by a name and there's no specific rule for naming them except that they should be unique.